# Graphicsmagick Image Comparison threshold value

Tags: gruntjs, graphicsmagick, centos7

I am using grunt for my test bed setup and currently it would generate bunch of screenshots for a given test case and it then compares those screenshots against the benchmarks I already stored in a different repository using graphicsmagick. But there seems to be minor difference in the screenshot between different flavors of linux(CentOS and Ubuntu), where the screenshots validation passes on Ubuntu but on CentOS, only one of the screenshots differs of the magnitude of 1e-9 due to which my test case fails.

Is there a way while using gm compare, I could specify a threshold to the image comparison so we throw an error only if the difference exceeds the threshold, otherwise not? I have been browsing through graphicsmagick tutorial but haven't been able to do that. Any pointers?

I am using the below code for image comparison:

```
gm.compare(screenshot1, screenshot2, options, function (err, isEqual, equality, raw) {
            assert(!err,filename + ' is different');
            equality.should.be.exactly(0);
            if err done(err);
})
```

The raw value is a string which has the normalized RGB Difference and the total difference.Any other option by which I can control the threshold so equality is zero if the difference is less than the threshold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm#compare) state that

> You may wish to pass a custom tolerance threshold to increase or decrease the default level of 0.4.

```
gm.compare('/path/to/image1.jpg', '/path/to/another.png', 1.2, function (err, isEqual) {
  ...
})
```

You can also pass the tolerance in your `options`-object

```
var options = {
  file: '/path/to/diff.png',
  tolerance: 1.2
}
```

edit: As that doesn't seem to work, you could just round the equality down if it's within your own (arbitrary threshold):

```
 gm.compare(screenshot1, screenshot2, options, function (err, isEqual, equality, raw) {
            var threshold = 0.0001;
            equality = equality < threshold ? 0 : equality;
            assert(!err,filename + ' is different');
            equality.should.be.exactly(0);
            if err done(err);
})
```

Comment: I tried that, but still the equality parameter returns a non zero value and hence, results in a failure. I believe the tolerance may be related to what gets highlighted in the diff image and does not result in ignoring the tolerance level during image comparison.

Comment: See my edit about just rounding the equality down if it's within the threshold (equality is the one that returns the `1e-9` right?)

Comment: Yes, I did the same thing, but slightly differently,     equality.must.be.below(threshold) where threshold is a variable defined globally and equals 1e-9. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Just chiming in because I was scratching my head about this too, the "tolerance" option is a bit unclear.  If you output the 'equality' callback paramter on any image that is not exactly the same you will get a non-zero value (where zero is perfect match), however even very dis-similar images will be very small values (I had a 2000px tall sprite sheet compared to a tiny 256x256 image and the equality value was 0.12).

What tolerance is, is it is the level at which the isEqual callback param will return true or false as it pertains to the equality parameter.

So if you want to know for certain that the images you are comparing are EXACTLY the same, set the tolerance to 0 like this

```
gm.compare('/path/to/image1.jpg', '/path/to/another.png', 0, function (err, isEqual) {
      ...
})
```

If you don't need them to be exactly equal but just close, ignore the threshold and output the equality to determine your threshold for later use.